# Splitting a multisequence fasta protein file into many files using Biopython

Tags: python, file, split, biopython, fasta

```
def batch_iterator(iterator, batch_size) :
    entry = True
    while entry :
        batch = []
        while len(batch) < batch_size :
            try :
                entry = iterator.__next__
            except StopIteration :
                entry = None
            if entry is None :
                #End of file
                break
            batch.append(entry)
        if batch :
            yield batch



from Bio import SeqIO

record_iter = SeqIO.parse(open("C:\\Users\\IDEAPAD\Desktop\\fypsplit\\protein.fasta"),"fasta")
for i, batch in enumerate(batch_iterator(record_iter, 1000)):
    filename = "group_%i.fasta" % (i + 1)
    with open(filename, "w") as handle:
        count = SeqIO.write(batch, handle, "fasta")
    print("Wrote %i records to %s" % (count, filename))
```

I am trying to split a fasta file using Biopython. I want to make it like 7 files in this example. But I am getting an error reading `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'id'`.

Can someone help me? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AttributeError is thrown in this line

```
count = SeqIO.write(batch, handle, "fasta")
```

because `SeqIO.write` expects an iterable or list of type `SeqRecord`. However, your `batch_iterator` produces a list of *methods* instead.

Why methods? Well, you are missing a function call here:

```
entry = iterator.__next__
```

should be

```
entry = iterator.__next__()
```

This makes the code run through without error.

For a test file consisting of 11 sequences, I got the following result - after changing the batch size from 1000 to 4 for testing purposes:

```
Wrote 4 records to group_1.fasta
Wrote 4 records to group_2.fasta
Wrote 3 records to group_3.fasta
```

Comment: hello, what if i am going to make into 7 files? instead of so many file?

Comment: Where does this number 7 come from? In a fasta file there can be multiple protein sequences. If there are 5 sequences, splitting into 5 files makes sense. If there are 100 sequences, splitting into 100 files makes sense. According to what criteria do you want to split your file?

Comment: my initial plan was to upload my whole genome protein sequence(fasta file) in the hmmer  in order to get the pfam id list of my genome.. but, that tool has a limitation of the sequence which is minimum 5000 bp..that is way i come across to split my protein sequence file into 7 files.. because the protein for the genome is 3224

Comment: I see. In that case your batch_iterator seems to do the job, if you add the brackets as I suggested. I tested it with a small sample file and a very small batch size. Updated answer.

Comment: @Mia The whole try-except clause can be replaced with `entry = next(iterator, None)`

Comment: hello @chris_Rands thank you for your help but it still split into single sequence which is it give me like 3317 files which is it seems not so applicable for me in order to upload them one file by one in the tool later

Comment: @LydiavanDyke thank you so much for your helps..now i managed to split my files into 7 files...have a great day and happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

using module available : [more-itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Dec 31 08:30:32 2020

@author: Pietro

"""


from Bio import SeqIO

from more_itertools import ichunked

fasta_file = ""C:\\Users\\IDEAPAD\Desktop\\fypsplit\\protein.fasta""
seqA = record_iter = SeqIO.parse(open(fasta_file),"fasta")


group = 1

for chunk in ichunked(seqA, 1000):
    with open(fasta_file+'_group_'+str(group), "w+") as file_write:
        for seq_record in chunk:
            SeqIO.write((seq_record),file_write, "fasta")
            group += 1
```